# Efficient Traversal of A Large Class

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to traverse a large python class, notably from pyvmomi (VMWare's tool for interacting vcenters) quickly.

My idea was to convert the class into elementary types using the `__dict__` attribute, traversing this dictionary recursively, but it is taking a long time (about 15 seconds per object), and I would like this process to be quicker.

Is there a more efficient means of traversing the object? `vars()` produces similar speeds, and the class is too large to support manual traversal.

The specific code that I'm using is:

```py
def map_obj(host,obj,f,prefix=""):
        # Traverse each element in a list
        if isinstance(obj,list):
                for i,v in enumerate(obj):
                        map_obj(host,v,f,prefix+"[%d]" % i)
                return
        if not hasattr(obj,"__dict__"):
                return f(host,prefix,json.dumps(obj))
        # Otherwise, traverse all attributes
        for k,v in obj.__dict__.iteritems():
                # This check is so that we don't grab internal attributes - not entirely positive its safe but pyVmomi seems to comply
                if not k.startswith('_'):
                        map_obj(host,v,f,prefix+"."+k)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "My idea was to convert the class into primitives" Python doesnt *have* primitives. But how exactly are you traversing the dict? What do you mean by manual traversal?

Comment: When I say primitives, I mean the standard types, numbers, strings, lists of these, etc, but something akin to the primitive types that you would find in another language.

Comment: As for how I'm traversing it, I'm looping over the items found in `__dict__`, and then recursing on them, behaving differently if its an array, an object, another class, or a standard type. As for manual traversal, I mean I can't just do 'a.b.c.d' repeatedly for every possible combination.

Comment: recursion generally is slow in python so you can consider an iterative solution, but I'm not sure how much there is to gain. if you post your actual code, there may be specific things that are inefficient, but otherwise, we can only speculate.

Comment: Ok, so `prefix+"[%d]"` will get inefficient as your depth increases, for starters. Use a `list` and `.append` to it. then `''.join(my_string_list)` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for speed gains, it's a good idea to run your code through a profiler, and see what is taking the time.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html

Even without that, I have a decent guess - function calls in Python are expensive, so recursive functions like yours can often be optimized by putting type checks before the recursion.  It makes for uglier, but faster, code.

Your leaf check looks to be:

```
    if not hasattr(obj,"__dict__"):
            return f(host,prefix,json.dumps(obj))
```

You can place that check and a call to `f` before the calls to `map_obj`.  That should eliminate a good host of function calls.